# Turning error reporting off php

Tags: php

I wanted to turn off the error reporting on a website. Googling for it I found that placing the code mentioned below in the website stops the errors from getting displayed on the screen. I placed it into my website but it did not work. Please help me out. Thanks

```
<?php

error_reporting(0); // Turn off all error reporting

?>
```

Comment: Does it do the same when you try ini_set('error_reporting',0); ?

Comment: Define "did not worked".

Comment: put 'phpinfo();' after that and check what the error settings are under 'core'

Comment: "I placed it into my website" WHERE did you place it? What file?

Comment: *"It doesn't work"* [doesn't explain the problem](http://stuck.include-once.org/#help3) enough. You need to elaborate on your input, expected and actual outcomes, or concretise error messages. In particular if you imply you still got error messages. And no, fatal/parsing errors cannot be trapped as that command would be executed afterwards.

Answer (score 59):

Tried this yet?

```
error_reporting(0);
@ini_set('display_errors', 0);
```

Comment: if i write error_reporting(0); or error_reporting(0); @ini_set('display_errors', 0) what is difference between Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Does this work?

```
display_errors = Off
```

Also, what version of php are you using?

Answer (score 5):

Read up on the [configuration settings](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting) (e.g., `display_errors`, `display_startup_errors`, `log_errors`)  and update your `php.ini` or `.htaccess` or `.user.ini` file, whichever is appropriate.

It works.

Comment: What do you mean by appropriate? I have both php.ini and .htaccess on the website. How should I know which one is **appropriate**? Please help. Thanks

Comment: If you have access to `php.ini`, it's better to make changes to that (in my opinion) as it's read once during start up and doesn't scatter your configuration across multiple folders.