# Error reporting in php session

Tags: php, session, reporting

I've moved my project to notebook and install wamp. After that, on my pages i have error

> Notice: Undefined index: email in index.php on line 4 Call Stack

On this line there is `$_SESSION['name'];` and I need this session.

I'm looking everywhere how to fix the problem, is there some solution in php.ini?

I can't change php file.

**SOLUTION**
First, thanks for the answer! I found solution :
Just edit php.ini and set :

```
error_reporting = 0
```

Comment: `$_SESSION['email'] = 'problem@solved.com';`.

Comment: Your solution... You can't be serious... Tell me you are not serious!

Comment: @JustSid , my solution? why???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not suppress error messages. Handle them instead,

this undefined index is triggered due to you trying to get a value from an array, where the key does not exist.

Example:

```
 echo $_SESSION['Testing'];
```

I have not started a session nor added anything to the session array. So the key does not exist, so the undefined index notice would be triggered.

```
 session_start();
 echo $_SESSION['Testing'];
```

The same as the previous example.

```
 session_start();
 $_SESSION['Testing'] = "Hello World";
 echo $_SESSION['Testing'];
```

This will not generate any messages as the key exists in the array.

Example 2:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['Testing'])){
  echo "Value Exists";   
}else{
  echo "Value does not exist"; 
}
```

This will check if the array key exists. if it does, print that the value exists.. If it does not, then print the value does not exist.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But on my computer i don't have problems with that. I am asking is there some way to change php.ini and set error reporting  to not show errors ?

Comment: @shapic94 There is a method, i'd go against it though. as if it's a local development zone, you should have error reporting set to E_ALL and Strict. So you can handle errors as they arise, and when it comes to production. You do not have any underlaying issues/complications with unhandled errors

Comment: @shapic94 PHP.ini, top answer with +2 votes. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10711517/turning-error-reporting-off-php    Change this in php.ini & restart the Apache Service

Comment: Thanks both, i found solutions.But in the future i will be careful with this, thanks again!