# Error reporting inside a php file for single page

Tags: php

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
echo 'Hello world'
echo 'Hello world';
?>
```

This statement has an error `echo 'Hello world'`
but error reporting is set to 0 so why does it not work and still shows an error?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Turning error reporting off php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10711517/turning-error-reporting-off-php)

Comment: Could you add the reported error msg, pls.

Comment: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO), expecting ',' or ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\series\3errorreporting.php on line 5`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
error_reporting(0);
@ini_set('display_errors', 0);
```

I must not forget to mention the source

[Turning error reporting off php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10711517/turning-error-reporting-off-php)

Comment: `<?php
error_reporting(0);
@ini_set('display_errors', 0);
echo 'Hello world'
echo 'Hello world';
?>`
tried it but still shows syntax error